# Vimeo embedded align to center

Tags: javascript, html, css, video, iframe

I am trying to align embedded vimeo video (iframe) on the center of page (horizontal and vertical). But I need to video scale increased or decreased with the size of the window preserving the aspect ratio (16:9).

Here I made a little illustration of what I want (LARGE GIF's):

Correct https://vk.com/doc199484568_437482326

Wrong https://vk.com/doc199484568_437482328

I try to use script Fitvids.js but it doesn't help me. 
I will happy to see solutions by any methods. Thanks for answers!

Answer (score 0):

I have this CSS snippet saved for responsive youtube videos, not sure where I got it. Maybe it can help you. You put a div with class 'videoWrapper' around the iframe then target it with the below CSS.

```
.videoWrapper {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* 16:9 */
    padding-top: 25px;
    height: 0;
}
.videoWrapper iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: It's works but wrong. I don't need fullscreen video but this snippet do this. I need to have possibility set up size of video. 

https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=1Cm8UgQqde

Comment: You can't both set up the size of the video AND make it change based on screen size. You can set up max-sizes and have it shrink from there?

Comment: Why I can't set up size and make video change when I change size of window?

But if this quite don't work how do I set-up max-sizes? (please use jsfiddle or examples, my knowledge of english is so poor, sometimes is easier to understand code instead of words. thanks)

Comment: Sure, check this out, wrapped it in a container then gave the container a max width and centered it https://jsfiddle.net/5rocoanm/